# Почему отладка прерывается?

Tags: javascript, ajax, отладка, xmlhttprequest

Я пытаюсь вытащить из другого сайта нужные мне ссылки и засунуть их в массив. Вроде бы всё делаю правильно, но массив получается на выходе странный. При отладке вот что происходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему меня выбрасывает в какой-то новый файл с единственной переменной? Встречаюсь с этой проблемой уже во втором проекте, но в первый раз я была уверена, что это из-за bubbling. В этот раз здесь явно нет никаких событий мыши и тому подобное.
Почему меня выкидывает в другой файл и отладка прерывается?(дальше шагать по коду не могу)

Код:

```
function getPostsLinksArray(homeUrl) {
var url = "https://www.thesimsresource.com/downloads/browse/category/sims4/order/downloads/";
var itemLink = "", data = "", postLink = "", postLinks = [];
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            itemLink = xhr.response.getElementsByClassName("item-link");
            for (var i = 0; itemLink.hasOwnProperty(i); i++) {
                postLink = homeUrl + itemLink[i].getAttribute("data-href");
                postLinks.push(postLink);
            }
        }
    }
};
xhr.send();
console.log(postLinks[0]);
```

Comment: Потому что это выполняется асинхронная функция, с пылу с жару, с event loop. Куда по вашему должен пойти трейс дальше? На следующее рандомное событие?

Comment: Я и забыла, что запрос асинхронен... Спасибо Вам

Comment: @vp_arth тогда именно поэтому в начале цикла у меня массив уже заполнен, когда по идее должен быть пустым? потому что он заполнился с запроса, который находится в коде ниже?

Comment: Похоже на то, зря вы делаете несколько запросов в одной функции, да ещё и результат в общую переменную пушите)

Comment: @vp_arth Раз Вы так говорите значит сейчас буду исправляться. А что бы мне таки контролировать асинхронный запрос, лучше промисы использовать или есть ещё какой-нибудь способ?

Comment: В первую очередь вынесите весь общий код, связанный с запросом, в отдельную функцию, можно с функцией обратного вызова. Потом можно переделать на Promise, А можно сразу посмотреть на [fetch](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch)

Comment: Кстати, в `xhr.onload` не нужно проверять readyState и status, это не `onreadystatechanged`, load - значит есть результат